# How to convert a parameter in FitNesse?

Tags: fitnesse

I am using FitNesse with Xebium for documenting/running automated test scripts.

I was wondering how these test scripts can be improved e.g. by removing duplication:

```
|scenario                 |Given a customer check with status positive|
|start app with customerId|1000001                                    |

|scenario                 |Given a customer check with status negative|
|start app with customerId|1000002                                    |

|scenario                 |Given a customer check with status error|
|start app with customerId|1000003                                 |
```

(... and so on)

I have the feeling that this can be put in one table, but how?

Comment: Why are you creating different scenario's? What is it that you are trying to achieve? You could just put the lines for each scenario in a single script, you could parameterize the scenario for the customerId. But that all depends on what you want, now you just create many scenarios, and nothing is being done/tested yet...

Answer (score 0):

I know its an old post, but I believe you can plan your acceptance tests something like below

```
|start app                                   |
|status  |given customer|whatever validation?|
|positive|1000001       |works fine          |
|negative|1000002       |can not be launched |
|error   |1000003       |can not be launched |
```